# How to set dynamic log filename using yaml config

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, yaml, python-2.x

I have a config file in my python project:

```
version: 1
formatters:
    logstashFormatter:
        (): project.formatter.LogstashFormatter
        message_type: logstash
        tags: null
        domainName: false
handlers:
    file:
        class: logging.handlers.WatchedFileHandler
        level: DEBUG
        formatter: logstashFormatter
        filename: app.log
        mode: a
root:
    level: DEBUG
    handlers:
        - file
    propagate: true
```

Is there any way to set dynamic filename (using timestamp or not)
to make each user write in his own file?

Comment: Hello, did you find how to fix this ? I'm interested in your solution. Thanks.

Comment: @Flo basically, I haven't found a solution, but I made a workaround: one way or another we should load .yaml file before passing it to logging configuration (in my case). So I replace `app.log` with current timestamp.

Comment: Yeah same here, i had to use a custom python code to dynamically build the filename. Thanks for the answer btw :)